# Is there a way to see "stack memory dump" in Java if StackOverflowError happens

Tags: java, memory, stack-overflow, jvm-hotspot

I'd like to analyze how a thread uses stack memory.

My application fails with StackOverflowError with the default stack size of 1Mb; but it works fine if I set stack size to 2mb.

`-Xss2m`

I'd like to see which objects (local vars, parameters etc) consume the stack memory. Is it possible in HotSpot?

(If it is important it is Java 8.)

Comment: The stack trace from the exception will show you which functions are being called, and in Java you have references and primitive types on the stack, so it isn't be too hard to figure out the size of a function's stack frame.

Comment: This is not very trivial, but most likely, not needed at all. Why do you want this? StackOverflowError is usually caused by a too deep call chain, not by particular local variables that you may find on the stack. Since HotSpot has no on-stack allocation, it's not technically possible for a single Java frame to grow too big. The problem is typically in the number of frames, not in their contents.